# How to to transform a String of Property Names into an object's Property Values

Tags: c#, properties

Many of my classes have a DisplayName property using string interpolation, for example:

```
  DisplayName = $"{CutoutKind} {EdgeKind} {MaterialKind}";
```

where each element in {} is a class Property Name.

What I would like to do is to retrieve the String being interpolated from the database, something like

```
displayName = SomeFunction(StringFromDatabase, this);
```

Where StringFromDatabase is a variable, value set from the database,  = "{CutoutKind} {EdgeKind} {MaterialKind}"

However I want to do this without using reflection

Is there some different way of achieving what I want?

Comment: Can you show you entire class. Also you want to the DisplayName property on your class to be set to a value from you database, is that the question? I don't understand what you mean by string interpolation..

Comment: your question is not clear,But I think you can override ToString() function in each class and write your own function. also if the function in all class are the same you inherent from a base class

Comment: If you assign the interpolated string to a `FormattableString`, you can muck around with it manually. i.e. `FormattableString x = $"...";`.

Comment: @markmnl String interpolation is performed by the  C# operator  '$'

Comment: @Mahdi I am not sure what is unclear?

Comment: @codran The issue is not to do with formatting the string, but in somehow 'parsing' a string like "{property name}" so that $ can interpolate it

String t = "{property name}" 
$"{t}" will evaluate to "{property name}"

so String t = GetFromDatabase() where GetFromDatabase() returns a string such as "{property name]" from the database will not work

Comment: Why you want to use a function to create displayName?

Comment: @Mahdi Does not have to be a function - but anything that takes in a String input and puts out a parsed String is by definition a function

There may be some other way of course...

Answer (score 1):

Doing this at runtime without using reflection would mean that a generic solution is not possible. You would have to write different method for *each class* you want to support. A very simple version:

```
static string SomeFunction(string format, MyClass instance)
{
    return format.Replace("{CutoutKind}", instance.CutoutKind.ToString())
                 .Replace("{EdgeKind}", instance.EdgeKind.ToString())
                 .Replace("{EdgeKind}", instance.MaterialKind.ToString());
}
```

Or a slightly more sophisticated version:

```
Dictionary<string, Func<MyClass, string>> propertyGetters = 
    new Dictionary<string, Func<MyClass, string>>
    {
        { "CutoutKind", x => x.CutoutKind.ToString() }
        { "EdgeKind", x => x.EdgeKind.ToString() }
        { "EdgeKind", x => x.MaterialKind.ToString() }
    };

static string SomeFunction(string format, MyClass instance)
{
    return Regex.Replace(@"\{(\w+)\}", 
        m => propertyGetters.HasKey(m.Groups[1].Value) 
                 ? propertyGetters[m.Groups[1].Value](instance) 
                 : m.Value;
}
```

But if you decide you don't want to have to write this kind of method for each class, here's a simple generic version using reflection:

```
static string SomeFunction<T>(string format, T instance)
{
    var propertyInfos = typeof(T)
        .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
        .ToDictionary(p => p.Name);
    return Regex.Replace(@"\{(\w+)\}", 
        m => propertyInfos.HasKey(m.Groups[1].Value) 
                 ? propertyInfos[m.Groups[1].Value].GetValue(instance, null) 
                 : m.Value;
}
```

Comment: Yes. But I do not want to use Reflection

Comment: @AndrewBingham I provided two examples that don't use reflection. Note that string interpolation in C# only works by translating the format string at compile time. There's no way to truly 'fake it' at runtime without reflection.

Comment: @ p.s.w.g.  Which examples do not use reflection??

Comment: @AndrewBingham The first two examples do not use reflection. Perhaps it was a bit confusing that I named the dictionary in my second example `propertyGetters` but notice that I use lambda expressions, not reflected `PropertyInfo`'s

Comment: Ah - I see what you mean. I was looking for a "general" solution,